# Calculating historical data over date ranges for up to 1 million rows

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I need to be able to calculate the average sales of employees over a period of time. At the moment, I am doing this by using MySQL to get the total sales per employee per day:

```sql
SELECT
    ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")) AS `date`,
    t1.name,
    sum(t1.sales) AS `total_sales`
FROM
    t1
WHERE
    t2_id IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
GROUP BY
    date, t1.name
ORDER BY
    t1.created_at,
    total_sales DESC;
```

And then calculating the averages with PHP (Laravel) by first grouping by the `date` column and then looping over all dates, getting the total sales amongst all employees in that day, and then looping over and calculating the average for each employee.

In case it helps:

```php
        $groupedTotals = $totals->groupBy('date');
        $aggregatedTotals = collect();

        foreach ($groupedTotals as $date => $employees) {
            $totalSales = $brands->sum('total_sales');

            $data = [];

            foreach ($employees as $employee) {
                $data[$employee->name] = [
                    'sales' => round($employee->total_sales / $totalSales * 100, 2),
                ];
            }
            $aggregatedTotals->put($date, $data);
        }

        return $aggregatedTotals;
```

When working with large (but I'm sure they aren't really "large large") datasets where the `t2_id IN()` will contain up to 1 million IDs, this is obviously extremely inefficient. The loading time for just 18,000 IDs is over 15 seconds.

I also tried calculating the averages with SQL with a correlated subquery:

Instead of `sum(t1.sales) AS`total_sales` I used:

```
    sum(t1.sales) / (
        SELECT
            SUM(sales)
        FROM
            t3
        WHERE
            t3.t2_id in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
            AND date(t3.created_at) = date(t1.created_at)) * 100 AS `average`
```

Which, whilst it did work, was substantially slower.

Some things to note, there is no guarantee that `t2_id` in unique. Think of `t2_id` as a `shift_id`. There is a unique correlation between `employee` and `t2_id`. There won't be multiple employees with the same name on the same shift. It's also therefore worth mentioning that there may be multiple `shift_id` values on any given `created_at` day.

Is it possible to do this more efficiently?

The data is not needed on the spot, and one alternative I'm considering is to every night calculate the averages for all "T2 IDs" on that day and store all of that in it's own table.  However, even with the averages stored, I'm unsure how efficient it will be.

The table structure for `t1` is:

`id` primary key

`t2_id` indexed

`name`

`sales`

`created_at`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t1`;
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t2_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sales` double(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sales_hash_index` (`hash`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `sales_shift_id_index` (`t2_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `sales_name_created_at_index` (`name`,`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3140922 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

### Update:

I'm currently able to achieve the desired results using:

```
SELECT
    `total_sales_for_employee`.`shift_date`,
    `total_sales_for_employee`.`name`,
    total_sales_for_employee.total / total_sales.total AS `average_slots`
FROM (
    SELECT
        `name`,
        shifts.shift_month AS `shift_date`,
        COUNT(*) AS `total`
    FROM
        `sales`
        INNER JOIN `shifts` ON `shifts`.`id` = `sales`.`shift_id`
    WHERE
        `shifts`.`t3_id` in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200)
        AND shifts.shift_month >= '2019-01-01'
    GROUP BY
        name,
        shift_date
    ) AS `total_sales_for_employee`
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            shifts.shift_month AS `shift_date`,
            COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS `total`
        FROM
            `shifts`
        WHERE
            `shifts`.`t3` in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200)
            AND shifts.shift_month >= '2019-01-01'
        GROUP BY
            `shift_date`
    ) AS `total_sales` ON `total_sales`.`shift_date` =
                               `total_sales_for_employee`.`shift_date`
ORDER BY
    `total_sales_for_employee`.`shift_date` ASC,
    `total_sales_for_employee`.`name` ASC;
```

Using virtual generated (indexed) columns for `shift_day`, `shift_week` and `shift_month`. In the shifts table indexes are:

`t3_id,id,review_day`
`t3_id,id,review_week`
`t3_id,id,review_month`

And on `sales` there is an index on `shift_id,created_at,name`

From the original schema:

`t1` is `sales`

`t2` is `shifts`

There is a relation between t3 and t2. Using  `t3_id`s instead of `t2_id`s in the WHERE's gives the same result but is less IDs in the WHERE which I think is quicker.

However, to me, this sort of thing should be done in less than 100ms. It currently takes 300ms with short ranges and `t3_id`s and 1-2 seconds for long ranges and more `t3_id`s

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you saying that you keep the name with every record?

Comment: @Vérace Yes. There aren't more than 5-15  names

Comment: `DATE(...)` is not sargable.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames added it to OP

Comment: @Shiv - I'm still struggling with the intent of `t2_id`.  It seems to limit _which_ "sales" are to be included in the totals.  Since it is "in the way" of making the query efficient, we should ponder how to avoid it.  You call it a "shift".  If the set of shifts is just "graveyard" shifts, then a categorizing the should would help to avoid that long `IN()`.

Comment: @RickJames You can think of the t2_id as a sale type of which there could be a couple thousand different types and the normal of sale types to look at could be any number.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(t1.created_at), t1.name, t2_id) FROM t1;`.  And, what is the purpose of `hash`?

Comment: `212680` and `117737` - we expect these to be a lot bigger as I'm currently on a test database.

`hash` is a relation to another table but isn't required for this query @RickJames

Comment: Alas, the counts suggest that using a Summary table would be futile.

Comment: @RickJames that was something I was considering, how come it would be futile though?

Comment: If those 3 values were to be the PK of the summary table, the table would have only half as many rows as the original table.  That's not much savings.

Comment: @RickJames I've just posted an update with something I just managed to get working but I still think it can be improved, are you able to take a quick look on that? P.S. Your site is extremely helpful!

Comment: This pattern is usually inefficient:  `FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...`  See if you can avoid having two derived tables like that.

Comment: I would have thought that using a window function in the first one similar to `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY shifts.shift_month) AS total_total` would have worked but it gives numbers that are too high @RickJames

Comment: @Shiv - "Too high" sounds like `JOIN` + `GROUP BY`.  When you need to do the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` _before_ doing the `JOIN`.

Comment: @RickJames I have just taken out the `FROM` subquery and added that extra bit to `SELECT` so there's no `JOIN`

Comment: @RickJames so the issue is that `SUM(COUNT(*))` gives the total number of sales, not the total number of shifts. I'd need to do something like `SUM(COUNT DISTINCT shift_id))` which isn't possible "yet"

Comment: `SUM(COUNT( ... ))` does not make sense.  Aggregation does not know how to handle nested functions like that.  `COUNT(DISTINCT shift_id)` is meaningful.